# Insert A list of objects into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert a list of objects into sql server table. However, currently, I have to open and close the sql connection each time I insert a record row.

I just wonder if there is a way I can insert all the objects in the record list at one time? Here is the code snippet.

```
public void InsertDataToDb()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    var records = GetRecords();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", item.param1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", item.param2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", item.param3);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add multiple rows within one query. Just be sure the parameters are unique.

Comment: An alternative is to create a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen But if I have 100 records in the list, how come I could add one by one?

Comment: I've found some info for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972974/how-should-i-multiple-insert-multiple-records

Comment: You might want to take a peek at this article and consider not using AddWithValue in the future. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos you remind me to write a stored procedure. For my problem here, I think using store procedure is a little bit overkilled. SP is good for more complicated logic than my code. Here I just wanted to insert some records.

Comment: @SeanLange Very useful, I will keep in mind. thanks!

Comment: @catlovespurple on the contrary. Using stored procedure for all data manipulation is valid and a great strategy. It is the first step in truly separating the data layer. When you have pass through queries like this embedded in your application it requires changes to the application when a simple change to the insert is required. Don't think of a stored procedure as a tool only to be used when the logic is complicated. The best procedures are simple and don't try to recreate programming logic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm making assumptions about your datatypes (change them as you need, based on what the actual DbTypes are), but something like this should do it:

```
    public void InsertDataToDb()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].
            ConnectionString;
        var records = GetRecords();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) " +
                    " VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", DbType.String);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", DbType.String);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", DbType.String);

            foreach (var item in records)
            {
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = item.param1;
                cmd.Parameters[1].Value = item.param2;
                cmd.Parameters[2].Value = item.param3;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'd also recommend invoking a transaction so that all 100 inserts can be done as a single transaction.

-- EDIT --

Regarding the transaction, here is about how you would add it:

```
conn.Open();   // already there -- to show you where to start the transaction

SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
string sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) " +
    "VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn, trans);
```

And then, before you close your connection (or after the last statement in the transaction, which can include selects, updates, whatever):

```
trans.Commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are working well. I wonder the transaction you'd recommend is to write a T-Store Procedure to do all these work at one time?

Comment: No, the transaction within ADO.net...  I didn't compile/test this and didn't want to risk making a mistake on the transaction piece, but it's pretty easy.    I'll fix it and show you what I mean.

Comment: Per your update, just as a side note, you can wrap the transaction in a `using` statement, its a easy way to ensure that the transaction gets rolled back if you leave the scope without calling `Commit()`. However because the connection is being closed anyway it does not really matter.

Comment: @Hambone I still think there needs for each statement in the sql transaction, how come we dump all the data at one time?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree. I would wrap both SqlTransaction and SqlCommand in a using statement.

Comment: @catlovespurple There will be 100 requests but all of those requests will be in a single transaction so if the process fails they all get rolled back and you don't get half inserted and half not. [Here is a full example](https://gist.github.com/leftler/b6a81300f24a8fea1ce3) of the code using a transaction, see that only one transaction is created.

Comment: @catlovespurple -- you don't necessarily dump all of the data at once, but a single transaction can definitely take thousands of actions.  It's very database-friendly, which is an often-overlooked element of programming.  All of Scott's comments are dead-on, as well.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for your full code. It's helpful and pretty clear.

Comment: what problem if i move  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); below of foreach loop?

Comment: @HienNguyen -- if you do that, it will only execute the very last insert.

Answer (score 9):

You could use an ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

With this library you could write something like this

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) 
                   VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)", records);
}
```

Comment: Dapper is a good library and it think it's a little bit overkill for my project. Thanks for your answer, if I have larger/more db involved project, I will consider Dapper.

Comment: It is up to you. I have used the direct ADO net approach thousands of times, so I think I understand your stance. But from my point of view, writing all that stuff is a big waste of time in particular with little projects

Answer (score -1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677318/how-to-run-multiple-sql-command-in-single-sql-connection)

But if you wanted to update yours, then do this

```
public void InsertDataToDb()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    var records = GetRecords();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        StringBuilder nonQuery = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var item in records)
        {
            nonQuery.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO TableName (param1, param2, param3) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2});",
                item.param1,
                item.param2,
                item.param3);
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nonQuery.ToString());

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Making the query un-parameterized is not good solution. You are introducing security holes and will now need to deal with things like proper formatting of dates and putting quotes around text. The correct way is to do the same concept but with parameters (See [Hambone's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33355911/80274))

Comment: ...how?  does it solve the problem that he is asking?  are you saying this because of security on sql injection?  ...and I upvoted Hambone's answer as it came at the same time i wrote mine.

Comment: How what? I pointed out 3 issues of why this is not a good solution.